# Is it possible to install windows 8 on windows phone device?

Tags: lumia, 7.x

I am currently in the process of getting a nokia lumnia 800 phone. Is it possible to install to get windows 8 beta installed on it as the operating system and if so, how can I go about it?

Comment: It might be that kernels are shared (now or in the future), but you will not want such big beast on your mobile.

Answer (score 6):

Is not possible install Windows 8 on Windows Phone Device. Maybe in a near future we can Update Windows Phone 7 to Windows Phone 8 (name not confirmed yet).

Comment: This is interesting - http://www.phonearena.com/news/Nokia-Lumia-900-can-run-Windows-Phone-8-claims-Nokia-Care_id30866  If it was not possible to upgrade at least 2nd generation phones to WP8, it would be quite a PR disaster for Microsoft and Nokia.

Comment: Ya. I saw the same chat session. Will be very bad if MSFT starts to do the same thing Android id. So many version.

Answer (score 2):

"Windows 8 on Arm" as it was known during the early development stages, to be released as Windows RT edition will only be made available to OEMs for pre-install. The retail versions will [only be available](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mvplead/windows-8-editions) for [Intel architecture](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/04/16/announcing-the-windows-8-editions.aspx).

Windows Phone devices are not based on Intel architecture, so you'll have to wait for any future update to be made available by Microsoft and your network operator (in a similar manner to how Mango has been made available to those original handsets) - of course this assumes there will be an edition to migrate existing phone devices from, but Microsoft are being very quiet on this.